# Is the following proof correct of why $\gcd(a,b)$ smallest linear combination of $a$ and $b$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof

This is the proof I have:

Lets see why $\gcd(a, b) $ is the smallest positive linear combination of $a$ and $b$:

Let $LC = \{ s'a + t'b : s', t' \in \mathbb{Z},  s'a + t'b > 0 \}$. 
By the definition $\gcd(a,b) \mid a$ and $\gcd(a,b) \mid b$.
Hence, it divides any linear combination of a and b i.e. $\forall (s'a + t'b) \in LC$, $ \gcd(a,b) \mid s'a + t'b $. Thus, $\gcd(a,b) \leq s'a + t'b $. But notice $\gcd(a,b)$ is itself a linear combination of $a$ and $b$. Thus, $\gcd(a,b) \in LC$. Therefore, $\gcd(a,b)$ cannot be larger than any $s'a + t'b$, because if it was larger then it wouldn't divide it. Therefore, it must be small than all elements of $LC$.

So I was wondering if this proof was correct or if there was a way to explain it in a better or more concise way. I only use as a given that we know Euclid's algorithm and hence know that there is some linear combination that expresses the gcd just not the smallest.

Comment: I would include a short demonstration that the gcd is a linear combination,instead of just saying it, unless that has already been shown in your book or class. While your proof is correct, you can express it more clearly: "Let $g =\gcd(a, b)$ and let $m$ be the least element of $LC$. Now ..., therefore $g \in LC$ and so $m \le g$. But ... Therefore $g | x \;\;\forall x \in LC$. In particular $g | m$ and so $g \le m$. Hence $g = m$."